# Can a simmerstat switch be fixed? And how?

Tags: switch, kitchens, range

I stumbled across this site and think it sounds like someone might be able to help me with my problem…

Let me outline… I have a cooktop (St George CC355, if that's useful) and it has two hotplates (well three, if you count the fact that one is a dual hotplate). The dual is the problem… it used to work, then suddenly it only worked on the full hotplate setting, which is actually, both the small and large on together). Because of this, I think I have narrowed the problem down to the control or the simmerstat switch, which I would love to just be able to replace (job done), but they no longer make it and have no alternative.

So, my question is can a simmerstat switch be fixed? And how? The switch is a TDL-205 if that helps. I really hope someone can give me some advice.

Kind regards, Lyndelle.

Answer (score 2):

The old simmerstats used a nichrome wire heat element to actuate a bi-metal on/off contact and so control temperature, the newer type appear to use a carbon track fixed to the bi-metal part to make it go on/off. I could never fix the nichrome type as the wire is so fine , hard to see, too tricky. The newer type, mine are MP101 need the blue case to operate as it has a bit of springy metal contact on the inside which provides electricity to the carbon track as the bi-metal makes the small movements, but it seems to wear out the contact point on the carbon track. A temporary fix can be a tiny bit of aluminium foil to make the contact. When removing the blue case try not to damage the very small clips that hold it firmy in place or it will have to be glued back with Araldite or similar. The old type worked for 40 years, the new ones maybe ten. My "fix" is still working after a year. This is not an instruction to do repairs as 240 volts is very dangerous. This is just my story. I always turn off the circuit breaker at the main board and remove the fuses in the stove before touching anything, using insulated tools. I test the simmerstat on an uncluttered work bench for safety, with a pilot light and dummy load. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

According to oxfordparts.com.au the part has been replaced/superceeded by TD3V-800K which I think is still available. I found a bunch of eBay listings anyways.

Also worth checking out this. If it looks the same as the switch you have it's probably the same

https://stoveconnection.com.au/shop/index.php/store/stove/controls/cooktop-controls/tl-205.html

Be aware the TD3V part might not look identical but the connections should be the same. Likely they improved the "guts" so they don't fail so soon...
Or so that they're cheaper to build.

Don't try to fix the switch, it'll never be right and you could melt stuff. Not to mention it's likely glued together.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will have a look at that part and I will also ask stove connection for their advice (I think I previously asked them, but they weren't much use, however, with the addition of a suggested part, maybe they will be more useful). Don't panic… I won't try to 'fix' the part (it was just a suggestion), Cheers L.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in Australia?
[This page](https://stoveconnection.com.au/shop/index.php/tl-205.html) may have a TL205 -  which is also advertised as a "divided controller".

The TDL-205 manufacturer's 2009 brochure advises that "TDL units are no longer available and that no replacement is possible" :-(

This [TD3-204](https://stoveconnection.com.au/shop/index.php/td3-204-everhot-simmerstat-grill-control.html.html) is for a divided element and MAY be suitable

If you can advise connections and **exact** * functionality we may be able to make suggestions re alternatives.

- EXACT detailed description of how it works.

Comment: Funny you should mention TL-205, because that's the control for the other burner (single medium). As for exact functionality, the way it should work is the switch operates both small & large elements. When turned to left, only the small inner element, with a top (low) to bottom (high) function, and, when turned to right, it operates both the small & large (outer) elements, same top-bottom (low-high). Presently, left hand side is not working, it operates the same as the right hand side, turning both on at once. I have pictures of the switch (might show the connections). Can I send them to you?

Comment: @LyndelleMcMillan Photos welcome. apptechnz gmail . || I take your operational description to mean that the LH side of the switch operates the outer element, which it shouldn't, as well as the inner, which it should. || I'd GUESS that this is due to there being contacts that disable the outer element and that these are operated by a "cam" on the lh side switch. | Alternative is an enabling switch for the rh side switch. | It seems likely that the contacts for this switch are "welded" together. If so, breaking the weld, then cleaning the contact faces may restore operation. Australia?

Comment: Thanks Russell, I have sent you an email with the pictures.